# How to pass userdata script on lambda python while launching ec2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to launch instance using aws lambda using python, but I cannot pass my base64 encoded userdata script.
The script looks like this:

```
import os
import boto3

AMI = "ami-052efd3df9dad4825"
INSTANCE_TYPE = "c6a.32xlarge"

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
                
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    instance = ec2.create_instances(
        ImageId=AMI,
        InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
        MaxCount=1,
        MinCount=1,
        UserData=*my script here*,
    )

    print("New instance created:", instance[0].id)
```

Comment: "I cannot pass my base64 encoded userdata script. " - why? What does it mean? Can you provide any information explaining what is your issue? Any errors?

Comment: You've left out any the user data script, and any error messages or unexpected behavior this code generates. There is not enough information to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify it without needing to base64 encode it, such as:

```py
user_data = '''
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test' > /home/ec2/test.txt
'''
```

Make sure the first line starts with a `#!`.

See also: [EC2 User Data not working via python boto command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44190556/174777) (It's old, but shows examples.)